# Using actionLayout inside fab in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I want to implement something like the `actionLayout` inside the fab. I used `actionLayout` in menu items but it does not seem to be working with fab.

So here is how I used it inside the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/someLayout"
        />
  .....
```

where `someLayout` is just a relative layout. Doing this to a fab does not work:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/someLayout"
            app:fabSize="normal"/>
```

can I use `actionLayout` in a fab or is there an alternative for it?

The reason I want to do this is because I want to use [this Android Library](https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton) and insert the button inside the Fab.

Comment: app:actionLayout="@layout/lsomeLayout"  .IS the layout name corect means lsomeLayout??

Comment: @NarenderReddy sorry, accidental input :) removed it

Comment: There is no such attribute in FloatingActionButton view itself. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html What are you trying to achieve? FABs should be simple so I'm wondering why you would like to place a RelativeLayout inside it?

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what you want to achieve but it seems you like some kind of floating menu, in that case take a look to some example projects in github like this: https://github.com/pmahsky/FloatingActionMenuAndroid

Comment: It is similar but I don't want to have sub items when clicking on the fab, I want to insert the button inside the fab

Comment: yes :) if you look at my question, I stated that I want to use a library inside the fab :)

Comment: oh man you should explain better what you really want to do... what library you want to implement on fab... i mean what does... because a generic answer is: you can create your own View that extends from Fab... like a mapper between your library and Fab...